# Disable ghost write file storage on cloud app engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, ghost-blog

I just try to install Ghost to Google Cloud App Engine. I follow the [official instruction](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ghost-on-app-engine-part-1-deploying) but I got error below:

> 2020-07-25 10:40:52 default[20200725t173735]  Error: EROFS: read-only
> file system, open
> '/workspace/node_modules/ghost/content/logs/https___yaskurweb_appspot_com_production.error.log'

Then I change `config.production.json` from:

```
"logging": {
    "level": "info",
    "rotation": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "transports": ["file", "stdout"]
}
```

to

```
  "logging": {
    "transports": [
      "stdout"
    ]
  },
```

But I got another error below:

> 2020-07-25 10:58:47 default[20200725t175429]  Error: EROFS: read-only
> file system, copyfile
> '/workspace/node_modules/ghost/core/frontend/services/settings/default-routes.yaml'
> -> '/workspace/node_modules/ghost/content/settings/routes.yaml'

I think it's caused when Ghost tries to copy routes.yaml file to another directory. So I need to know how to disable writing any file in Ghost?

my full `config.production.json` is:

```
{
  "url": "https://myproject.appspot.com",
  "fileStorage": false,
  "server": {
    "port": 8080,
    "host": "0.0.0.0"
  },
  "database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "host": "*",
      "port": "3306",
      "user": "dev",
      "password": "*",
      "database": "test_db"
    }
  },
  "mail": {
    "transport": "Direct"
  },
  "logging": {
    "transports": [
      "stdout"
    ]
  },
  "process": "systemd",
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "content/"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that config set content path to node_modules. it's should be installed root path.

so I changed from:

```
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "content/"
  }
```

to

```
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "/workspace/content/"
  }
```

And then work perfectly...